# After adjusting .htaccess links cause Too Many Redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm hosting 2 different sites, 1 of those is made with Wordpress. The folder structure looks like this:

```
root
  - wordpress
  - oldWebSite
```

When I access my domain, I would like to be redirected to the wordpress folder, without showing the folder name in the URL.

- URL: `example.com`
- Redirect: `example.com/wordpress`
- Show: `example.com`

I achieved this with the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wordpress)
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1
```

In the Wordpress settings I set:

- WordPress-Address (URL): https://example.com/wordpress
- Website-Address (URL) https://example.com

---

The redirected to the main page of Wordpress works correctly. Also, the links on my page look as expected: `https://example.de/hello-world/`.

But when I follow the links, I get into an endless loop of redirects: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Do I need to adjust my `.htaccess`?

Comment: Remove this WordPress-Address (URL): https://example.com/wordpress part keep WordPress-Address (URL): https://example.com/ if you are rewriting it will for content also.

Comment: And a side note: what you are doing is _not_ redirecting. You internally rewrite. That is something different.

Comment: @aviboy2006: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Still getting endless redirects.

Comment: @arkascha: Is there a better solution for my problem?